# How to fetch more data and store it in the state correctly in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to fetch more data from my api. I'm using the spread operator but It doesn't add to the state in a correct form.

After fetching I get this array. On array[5] it adds an extra array. Instead of that I want it to add to the existing ones.

```
0: {route_id: 7, price: 16760, distance: 111, shift_time: 20, max_load: 250, …}
1: {route_id: 2, price: 0, distance: 0, shift_time: 0, max_load: 100, …}
2: {route_id: 3, price: 0, distance: 0, shift_time: 0, max_load: 55, …}
3: {route_id: 4, price: 0, distance: 111, shift_time: 20, max_load: 240, …}
4: {route_id: 1, price: 0, distance: 0, shift_time: 0, max_load: 57, …}
5: (5) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
```

My code:

```
 axios(config)
        .then(function (response) {
            
            setRefreshing(false)
            setCardLoading(false)
            console.log(response.data);
            if(response.data.status_code === 200) {
                setRoutes([...routes, response.data.response])
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like you need to spread your response also, like:

```
setRoutes([...routes, ...response.data.response]);
```